# Get specific record thats updated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, abaddressbook

I'm trying to know which record update in `AddressBook` to modify it in my app.
Because if user have many contacts that will let the app get slower so I need to know how to get the specific one that update?

```
  ABAddressBookRef book = ABAddressBookCreate();
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(book, addressBookChanged, (__bridge void *)(self));

  void addressBookChanged(ABAddressBookRef reference,
                            CFDictionaryRef dictionary,
                            void *context){}
```

Comment: I suggest reading the official documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/BasicObjects.html

Comment: read it found nothing :(